# Using Doxygen \xrefitem, \todo, etc. commands in \file context, without member context (namespace/class/procedure)

Tags: doxygen

I am documenting Tcl source code, where some of the files get executed by being 'sourced', so the only Doxygen context in them is \file at the top (no namespace, proc, class, etc.)

In these "\file"-only contexts, when I use \xrefitem commands (or any derivative, ex. \todo \bug, etc.), Doxygen does not extract the information.

Is there a way to 'convince' Doxygen to extract these?

Any other trick that would make this work?

--------------[2014-05-16 Edit Below]--------------

As requested, here is an example of a small source code file after it has had doxygen tags added.  The header of the file is picked up correctly, but the \todo item is totally ignored.

```tcl
## \file pre_vsi.tcl
# \verbatim
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HEADER $Id$
# HEADER_MSG    Project
# HEADER_MSG    Tool Version
# HEADER_MSG    Copyright Notice
# HEADER_MSG
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DESCRIPTION:
# * This script runs Verdi Signoff-LP.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# \endverbatim

# Example items that might be best applied in the pre script

if { $TEV(lp_mode) == "NETLIST" || $TEV(lp_mode) == "PGNETLIST"} {
  ## \todo "This is a todo item"
  #
  # and a paragraph for a todo item
  #
  infer_source
  redirect $RPT(basename).infer_source { infer_source }
  # create_source <blah>
  # remove_source <blah>
}

if {0} {
  # example items that might be best applied in the pre-script
  configure_lp_tab
  waive_lp
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# End Of File
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you have evidence that the files are being parsed by Doxygen at all?

Comment: Yes, I get the file listed by Doxygen and source code listing included.

Comment: Would it be possible to see a short piece of source code - just so we can be completely clear on the problem?